# Proof that nilspaces are orthogonal with respect to Killing form

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm reading Serre's book about semisimple complex Lie algebras and having problem to understand one part of a proof.
The theorem states, that the restriction of the Killing form $B$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ to a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is nondegenerate. $\mathfrak{h}$ can be viewed a nilspace of $\operatorname{ad} x$ (with $x$ some element in $\mathfrak{g}$).

Within the proof he uses that the nilspaces of $\operatorname{ad} x - \lambda$ and this of $\operatorname{ad} x -\mu$ are orthogonal with respect to $B$ when $\lambda + \mu$ is not $0$. I have no idea how I would calculate that or show that it holds.

Also in the end when we have $\mathfrak{g}$ writen as a orthogonal sum, why does it follow from that that the restriction is nondegenerate. I have read that the restiction of a nondegenerate form is nondegenerate iff the intersection of $\mathfrak{h}$ and its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$. Is this the reason in this case?

Here is the theorem and proof:

> **Theorem 3**.  *Let $\mathfrak h$ be a Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$.  Then:*
>
> (a) *$\mathfrak h$ is abelian.*
>
> (b) *The centralizer of $\mathfrak h$ is $\mathfrak h$.*
>
> (c) *Every element of $\mathfrak h$ is semisimple* (cf. Sec. II.5)*.*
>
> (d) *The restriction of the Killing form of $\mathfrak g$ to $\mathfrak h$ is nondegenerate.*
>
> (d) By Corollary 2 to Theorem 2, there is a regular element $x$ such that $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak g_x^0$.  Let
>
> $$\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_\alpha^0 \oplus \sum_{\lambda \ne 0} \mathfrak g_x^\lambda$$
>
> be the canonical decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ with respect to $x$ (cf Prop. 2).  If $B$ denotes the Killing form of $\mathfrak g$, then a simple calculation shows that $\mathfrak g_x^\lambda$ and $\mathfrak g_x^\mu$ are orthogonal with respect to $B$ provided that $\lambda + \mu \ne 0$.  We therefore have a decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ into mutually orthogonal subspaces
>
> $$\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_x^0 \oplus \sum_{\lambda \ne 0} \mathfrak g_x^\lambda \oplus \mathfrak g_x^{-\lambda}.$$
>
> Since $B$ is nondegenerate, so is its restriction to each of these subspaces, giving (d) since $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak g_x^0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof. Use the standard grading of $\mathfrak{g}$ by weights, i.e., for $\alpha\in\mathrm{Hom}(\mathfrak{h},\mathbf{C})$, one has $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha=\{x\in\mathfrak{g}:\forall h\in\mathfrak{h},[h,x]=\alpha(h)x\}$. In particular $\mathfrak{g}_0=\mathfrak{h}$.

If $\alpha$ is a nonzero weight, we have $$\langle \mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}_\alpha\rangle=\langle \mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}_\alpha]\rangle=\langle [\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}],\mathfrak{g}_\alpha\rangle=0.$$

So if $x\in\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g}_0$ is in the kernel of the Killing form restricted to $\mathfrak{h}$, then it is in the kernel of the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}$, and hence $x=0$. The result is proved.

---

Edit: let's not take for granted that $\mathfrak{h}$ is abelian. For $h\notin\mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$, we have
$$\langle h,x\rangle=\frac1{\alpha(h)}\langle h,\alpha(h)x\rangle=\frac1{\alpha(h)}\langle h,[h,x]\rangle=\frac1{\alpha(h)}\langle [h,h],x\rangle=0.$$
If $h\in\mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$, just pick $h'\notin \mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$. Then $h+h',h'\notin\mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$. So $\langle h,x\rangle=\langle h+h',x\rangle-\langle h',x\rangle=0$.

Comment: This proves the main result. But the sub-result can be proved in the same way, writing, for $\alpha,\alpha+\beta\neq 0$, $\langle\mathfrak{g}_\alpha,\mathfrak{g}_\beta\rangle=\langle [\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}_\alpha],\mathfrak{g}_\beta\rangle=\langle\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha,\mathfrak{g}_\beta]\rangle\subset\langle\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha+\beta}\rangle=0$

Comment: For comparison, Serre seems to use the opposite notation, writing $\mathfrak g^\alpha$ where you write what I think of as the more standard $\mathfrak g_\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you. About the last part that ⟨ h, g_{\alpha+\beta} ⟩ =0, why does this hold. Is it because [h,h]=0? In the book this is shown by using the theorem, so it wouldn't make sense to use it in the proof. Or is there a different explanation, I am not seeing?

Comment: @paula That $\langle h,g_{\alpha+\beta}\rangle=0$ is proved in the answer (well, with $\alpha$ in the role of $\alpha+\beta$).

Comment: But don't we use [h,h]=0 there or why is ⟨[h,h],g_α⟩=0?

Comment: @paula yes, I'm using (a) to prove (d).

Comment: Hm, Serre does it the other way around so he later uses d) to show a) and b). Do you know if there is a way to calculate the Killing Form of the nilspaces, without using this property?